# feed-rss2 php file in wordpress giving server error

Tags: php, wordpress, rss2

My website developed in WordPress. In google search console I all of the below listed pages are getting 500 error. I am encountering a RSS feed error on your WordPress site? Recently one of our readers asked us how to fix WordPress RSS feed errors. There are multiple type of RSS feed errors.

**/wp-includes/feed-rss2.php**

```
    <?php
/**
 * RSS2 Feed Template for displaying RSS2 Posts feed.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

header( 'Content-Type: ' . feed_content_type( 'rss2' ) . '; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ), true );
$more = 1;

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) . '"?' . '>';

/**
 * Fires between the xml and rss tags in a feed.
 *
 * @since 4.0.0
 *
 * @param string $context Type of feed. Possible values include 'rss2', 'rss2-comments',
 *                        'rdf', 'atom', and 'atom-comments'.
 */
do_action( 'rss_tag_pre', 'rss2' );
?>
<rss version="2.0">
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
    <?php
    /**
     * Fires at the end of the RSS root to add namespaces.
     *
     * @since 2.0.0
     */
    do_action( 'rss2_ns' );
    ?>

<channel>
    <title><?php wp_title_rss(); ?></title>
    <atom:link href="<?php self_link(); ?>" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link><?php bloginfo_rss( 'url' ); ?></link>
    <description><?php bloginfo_rss( 'description' ); ?></description>
    <lastBuildDate><?php echo get_feed_build_date( 'r' ); ?></lastBuildDate>
    <language><?php bloginfo_rss( 'language' ); ?></language>
    <sy:updatePeriod>
    <?php
        $duration = 'hourly';

        /**
         * Filters how often to update the RSS feed.
         *
         * @since 2.1.0
         *
         * @param string $duration The update period. Accepts 'hourly', 'daily', 'weekly', 'monthly',
         *                         'yearly'. Default 'hourly'.
         */
        echo apply_filters( 'rss_update_period', $duration );
    ?>
    </sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency>
    <?php
        $frequency = '1';

        /**
         * Filters the RSS update frequency.
         *
         * @since 2.1.0
         *
         * @param string $frequency An integer passed as a string representing the frequency
         *                          of RSS updates within the update period. Default '1'.
         */
        echo apply_filters( 'rss_update_frequency', $frequency );
    ?>
    </sy:updateFrequency>
    <?php
    /**
     * Fires at the end of the RSS2 Feed Header.
     *
     * @since 2.0.0
     */
    do_action( 'rss2_head' );

    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
        ?>
    <item>
        <title><?php the_title_rss(); ?></title>
        <link><?php the_permalink_rss(); ?></link>
        <?php if ( get_comments_number() || comments_open() ) : ?>
        <comments><?php comments_link_feed(); ?></comments>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <pubDate><?php echo mysql2date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_post_time( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', true ), false ); ?></pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[<?php the_author(); ?>]]></dc:creator>
        <?php the_category_rss( 'rss2' ); ?>

        <guid isPermaLink="false"><?php the_guid(); ?></guid>
        <?php if ( get_option( 'rss_use_excerpt' ) ) : ?>
        <description><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss(); ?>]]></description>
        <?php else : ?>
        <description><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss(); ?>]]></description>
            <?php $content = get_the_content_feed( 'rss2' ); ?>
            <?php if ( strlen( $content ) > 0 ) : ?>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<?php echo $content; ?>]]></content:encoded>
    <?php else : ?>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss(); ?>]]></content:encoded>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( get_comments_number() || comments_open() ) : ?>
        <wfw:commentRss><?php echo esc_url( get_post_comments_feed_link( null, 'rss2' ) ); ?></wfw:commentRss>
        <slash:comments><?php echo get_comments_number(); ?></slash:comments>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php rss_enclosure(); ?>
        <?php
        /**
         * Fires at the end of each RSS2 feed item.
         *
         * @since 2.0.0
         */
        do_action( 'rss2_item' );
        ?>
    </item>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Kindly help me to resolve it out.

Comment: A 500 error is a server side error and is most easily diagnosed by looking at the log on the server. Please [edit] the question to include relevant entries from that log.